# Very odd characters in a mysql dump -- what to do?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've got weird data mangling my data migration.  These weird characters are embedded as-is in the actual mysql dump file:

---

```
Ã¥Å’â€”Ã¤ÂºÂ¬Ã¤Â¸Å“Ã¦â€“Â¹Ã¥Ââ€ºÃ¦â€šÂ¦Ã¥Â¤Â§Ã©â€¦â€™Ã¥Âºâ€”<br />\n<br />\nÃ¢â‚¬Å“The impetus
```

---

I've been given mysql data dumps with those kinds of chars in them.  I'm importing the data into Drupal, by first recreating the mysql tables, and then querying against them using Drupal's Migrate module.

Code looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `news`;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) default NULL,
  `puid` int(11) default NULL,
  `headline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `teaser` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) default NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `body` text,
  `caption` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `gid` int(11) default NULL,
  `feature` text,
  `related` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `change1_time` int(11) default NULL,
  `change2_time` int(11) default NULL,
  `change1_user` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `change2_user` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `expires` datetime default NULL,
  `rank` char(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `expires` (`expires`),
  KEY `rank` (`rank`),
  KEY `puid` (`puid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `headline` (`headline`,`teaser`,`body`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6976 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Fastest solution is the winner here -- I'm on a tight deadline, and really suffering over here!  I've tried a search and replace solution, but there appear to be too many different types of weird data.  I can orchestrate a new data dump, if I know what to tell them (how to do the data dump).

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you know the cleartext that the example above would equate to? Ot do you just look for a solution to remove these characters?

Comment: I'd say your data was exported using encoding A (most likely UTF-8) and is now being read using encoding B (possibly ISO-8859-1). You need to instruct the import to treat the incoming data as UTF-8.

Comment: Only the weird characters are embedded just like that in the actual mysql dump file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I played a bit with the [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) you quoted in your post.  It looks like it was originally Chinese text in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, which was interpreted as Latin text in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, *re-encoded* in UTF-8 and again interpreted as Windows-1252 (and finally once more encoded as UTF-8 when you posted it here).  So it's not just mojibake, it's *double* mojibake.

Also, at some point, a byte was lost from the middle of the string (probably because it was one of the undefined code points in Windows-1252), mangling one of the original characters.  Running the text through the encoding chain in reverse (encode as Windows-1252, decode as UTF-8, repeat), I get the output:

```
北京东方�悦大酒店<br />\n<br />\n“The impetus
```

where the replacement character `�` stands for the mangled character.

Comment: How did you go about your investigation?  A script?  What would you suggest as a path out of this mess?

Comment: I used the Perl [Encode module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) for the conversions. (`iconv` probably would've worked too.) At first I thought it was UTF-8 decoded as ISO Latin 1, but when I tried that I noticed that there were some characters in it like `“` and `€` that didn't belong in the ISO Latin 1 repertoire, so it was probably Windows-1252 instead.  Then, when I tried that, I got _more_ mojibake as output, so I tried it again. As for fixing it, _if_ those missing bytes are missing from the data itself (rather than just from the sample you cut and pasted here), it may be unfixable.

Comment: Gulp.  Thank you.  Do you know of a PHP equivalent?  I'm migrating thousands of pages of data, so a few broken strings here and there is not a deal-breaker.

Comment: I need to make sure I understand you.  In order to end up with correct UTF8 output, I need to take my current string, encode it as 1252, decode it as UTF8, encode it as 1252, and finally decode it as UTF8?  Then I can safely deposit it in a UTF8 collated MySQL database?

Comment: More or less. (It's a bit ambiguous because I can't actually tell how the data is encoded on your computer based only on what you pasted here.) What you could do is open the dump file (in whatever manner you used to get the examples above), save (a copy of) it as CP1252, open it as UTF-8 and save it again as CP1252. That should give you a file which is actually in UTF-8, and can be loaded into MySQL as such. However, it's quite possible that some of the characters might be irrevocably corrupted.

Comment: Ok -- I ran my sql dump files through something like this:

$raw = file_get_contents( $file . '.sql');
$convertA = mb_convert_encoding( $raw, 'WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8' );
$convertB = mb_convert_encoding( $convertA, 'UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252' );
$convertC = mb_convert_encoding( $convertB, 'WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8' );
file_put_contents( 'converted.' . $file . '.sql', $convertE );

Comment: on screen, i used to see this sort of output:
Ã¤Â¸Â­Ã¦â€“â€¡
Chino FranÃƒÂ§ais
FrancÃƒÂ©s PortuguÃƒÂªs
PortuguÃƒÂ©s 
EspaÃƒÂ±ol InglÃƒÂ©s
English

Now I see this:
ä¸­æ–‡
Chino FranÃ§ais
FrancÃ©s PortuguÃªs
PortuguÃ©s 
EspaÃ±ol InglÃ©s
English

Comment: Is there a next step you could recommend -- I feel like things just got a lot closer, but I'm not sure...  the target would be:  中文
Chino Français
Francés Português
Portugués 
Español Inglés
English

Comment: Just convert twice to CP1252 from UTF-8, not in the opposite direction:  `$raw = file_get_contents( $file . '.sql'); $convertA = mb_convert_encoding( $raw, 'WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8' ); $convertB = mb_convert_encoding( $convertA, 'WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8' ); file_put_contents( 'converted.' . $file . '.sql', $convertB );`

Comment: I'm still running into issues, but this is such great help, thank you so so much!

Comment: Doing two encodings, when I try to import strings from the database into another system (Drupal/MySQL), the string truncates at the first "odd" character.  When I do a single reverse encoding, there is no truncation, and i see things like -------- hile I was clerking for her,â€ said Yarger. â€œShe strongly r --------- in html output and things like -----------  main Ã¢â¬Åreading room.Ã¢â¬<U+009D><br />\n<br />\nÃ¢â¬ÅThe Goodson libr ----------- in the original dump.  the <U+009D> really stands out as more weirdness to me.  Are there UTF8 strings embedded inside the 1252 original encoding?